# How to do intersection, union and difference in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

How to do intersection, union and difference in DolphinDB?
How to perform intersection, union and difference in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should conver the data to a set before intersection, union and symmetricDifference:

```py
a=1 2 3
b=2 3 5
a1=set(a)
b1=set(b)
//intersection
intersection(a1,b1)
a1 & b1
//union
union(a1,b1)
a1 | b1
//symmetricDifference
symmetricDifference(a1,b1)
a1 ^ b1
```